# Using Serial Plotter with Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visualstudio

I'm using the [Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino) to develop for Arduino which works great.

It doesn't have a Serial Plotter like the regular Arduino IDE, which I need to debug this project. I can run the Arduino IDE's Serial Plotter alongside Visual Studio Code without too much of a problem.

However, if I try to compile and upload from Visual Studio Code while the Arduino IDE is running, the port is busy (not a surprise):

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/cu.usbmodem14201": Resource busy
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

So I have to keep exiting and relaunching the Arduino IDE every time I build.

Anyone have a suggestion for how to work around this? Using an iMac as development environment.

Comment: isn't it enough to close Serial Monitor window?

Comment: this does work, but is still kind of annoying... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Without very specialized software that can create two new devices with the correct "teeing" policy, it's not going to be possible.  Only one program can open a serial port at a time (certainly and have it get anything intelligible out of it...)

I would suggest you may want to add a second serial port.  Use an FT232 adaptor to communicate on another serial connection (or a SoftwareSerial connection at a pinch) for your debugging information.  You really want a board with more than one serial port for this - or a board with a native USB for programming and a hardware serial port for data communication.

Another alternative is to ditch the serial for programming altogether and program your board through a dedicated programmer, thus leaving your serial port free for data communication.

Answer (score -1):

Try teleplot extension in vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit so you can expand on your answer. As it currently stands, you answer does not meet the quality standards for this site. EG. Add a link, provide a summary of teleplot, answer how this extension solves the problem the OP was having.